# Picking contact information in android

Tags: android

I'd like to set up something to launch the built-in contact picker, and let a user choose an email, phone number, etc, then get said address/phone number back in my activity.

Am I correct in assuming that this isn't possible with android? It seems like you have to at least build a dialog yourself to choose in the case where a contact has multiple phone numbers/emails.

Even before that though, there doesn't seem to be a way to choose both phone numbers and emails simultaneously.

Is something like https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker or rolling your own UI the only way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly possible and straight forward with android. You don't need to create any dialog box or anything for it. Just lauch the built in contact picker Activity via an Intent.

It you have to launch the intent from some event handler

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

You should also have to implement

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

to receive URI of the contact user picked.

Thousands of tutorials are available on INTERNET on how to do it. Google is your friend.
Here is one http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/

Comment: i think he needs more than this. it's unclear , but maybe he wishes to have some fields returned to him, based on what the user has done. if it's too customizable, he will need to create his own solution for this, which also read and write info into the contact.

Comment: Nothing in this answer seems to address the scenario where a contact has multiple numbers/email addresses, nor does it address how to launch the contact picker activity in such a way that emails and phone numbers can be selected (not just one or the other, or entire contact profiles), with the results somehow obtained by the calling activity.